Windows recognizes my SD Card as a USB Drive
I have Temporary Write Protection toggled on for my 64GB SD Card. I want to toggle it off using sdtool on my Ubuntu VM on VirtualBox.
However, on my Ubuntu Device, the SD Card shows up as /dev/sdb with partition /dev/sdb1 when I run lsblk rather than showing up as a raw block MMC device. I think that has to do something with how windows is recognizing my SD Card, It shows up as a disk drive in Device Manager when I use a Micro SD Card plugged into SD Card Adapter that is plugged into the SD Card Reader of my laptop as well as when i plug in a SD Card Reader into my USB Port. It is necessary that the device shows up as a MMC so that sdtool can do it's job.
Since VMs use Virtual Hardware, maybe It is possible to pass a MMC device rather than a usb drive to the VM? I have read this but the question is not tuned towards VMs.
Any possible fixes?
Is it also possible to skip this hassle and directly toggle the TEMP_WRITE_PROTECTION in the CSD Register? If so, how would I do that?
I am using the SD Card on my Ubuntu VM by following Access SD Card on Ubuntu and furthermore giving Administrator priviliges to VBoxSVC.exe and running VirtualBox as an Administrator

The answer in your linked Q&A says it all: your computer has a USB-connected card reader. (Internal USB, that is.) You only get mmcblk devices from PCI-connected (SDHCI) card readers, which allow the OS to talk directly to the card (i.e. send actual MMC commands), whereas USB readers translate everything into SCSI (and as a result, instead of talking to the card, the OS can only talk to the reader). This is also the reason why you can easily pass the device to the VM. What you want to do isn't possible.

Alright, thanks for the heads up. Could you write it as an answer so that I can mark the question as closed

No, I won't write and answer as this is a duplicate.

Well, I have mentioned that... ~"Since VMs use Virtual Hardware, maybe It is possible to pass a MMC device rather than a usb drive to the VM?" which is not what they have enquired

No, VMs can't invent devices that doesn't exist in the host. They may emulate some but within reason and logic. What you want isn't possible in the host let alone in a VM, end of story.

And this seems to be an X-Y problem. How exactly did you toggle Temporary Write Protection when you couldn't in the first place? Aren't you perhaps confusing it with a read-only card that's about to fail?
